# Unable to get the shared data in service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to the AngularJS, and came to a weird situation, where I am unable to share the data between my two controllers, PersonDetailCtrl and PersonListCtrl and service ContactService. Below is the code for each of the components above mentioned

**Code for PersonDetailCtrl**

```
app.controller('PersonDetailController', function ($scope, ContactService, $rootScope){
$scope.selectedPerson = ContactService.selectedPerson;
}
```

**Code for PersonListCtrl**

```
app.controller('PersonListController', function ($scope, ContactService, $rootScope) {

$scope.search = "";
$scope.order = "email";
$scope.persons = ContactService.persons;
$scope.selectedPerson = ContactService.selectedPerson;

$scope.selectPerson = function (person, index) {
    $scope.selectedPerson = person;
    ContactService.selectedPerson = person;
};

$scope.sensitiveSearch = function(person) {
    if ($scope.search) {
        return person.name.indexOf($scope.search) == 0 ||
                 person.email.indexOf($scope.search) == 0;
    }
    return true;
};
});
```

**ContactService**

```
app.service('ContactService', function() {
return{

    'selectedPerson': null ,
    'persons': [
        {
            "name": "Gregory Huffman",
            "email": "Praesent@pedenec.net",
            "birthdate": "2015-03-23T18:00:37-07:00",
            "phonenumber": "07624 073918",
            "address": "5880 Sed, Street",
            "city": "Denderbelle",
            "country": "Ethiopia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tad Vazquez",
            "email": "dapibus.gravida@necimperdietnec.co.uk",
            "birthdate": "2015-12-28T06:02:56-08:00",
            "phonenumber": "(016977) 1036",
            "address": "830-6354 Cubilia Rd.",
            "city": "Sulzbach",
            "country": "Liechtenstein"
        }]
};
});
```

Can anyone explain me, why I do not get the `selectedPerson` in the `PersonDetailCtrl`. I know, we can get it through the dot Notation, but I want to know, why this won't work?

Is it because of the Prototypical Inheritance, each of the controllers, make their own new `persons` and `selectedPerson` Properties. If this is the case, then why i get all the persons from the `ContactService.person` assignment?

Code Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/y9bLxdua/

Comment: Please put the complete service. Would want to have a look at it.

Comment: Refactored the service

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `angular.service` to create this service, shouldn't you be placing those properties on `this`? This looks like a Factory instantiation more then a Service. The other problem is related to references. So depending on when the Detail controller gets loaded, it'll get the current value of `selectedPerson` but not any updates thereafter since you are changing the memory location stored in `selectedPerson`.

For example, say this was the order of events:

1. PersonListController is loaded
2. $scope items are set...
3. PersonDetailController is loaded
4. $scope items are set... $scope.selectedPerson = null
5. PersonListController changes selectedPerson to 'abc'
6. PersonDetailController does not receive the update and still has null

My recommendation, change your Service to a Factory. The only difference is its not created with the new keyword, so your returned object works just fine.

```
angular.module('myMod').factory(/* same as service */)
```

My second recommendation to avoid using `$scope.$watch` or something similar. Store the parent object in your controller so that when Angular runs its digest cycle is has to call `parent.selectedPerson` which means it'll lookup the new value vs looking directly at `$scope.selectedPerson`which doesn't change once set. Make sense?

```
$scope.ContactService = ContactService;
```

Which in this specific case isn't the greatest, putting the full service on the scope but it gets the point across for `parent.selectedPerson`

The alternative as I said would be to add a watch expression like this:

```
// This is an extreme shorthand to achieve what you need
// It runs each time the digest cycle does, updating your $scope.selectedPerson
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return $scope.selectedPerson = ContactService.selectedPerson; 
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me why it wont get the update? Its this a two way data-binding?

Comment: When your PersonDetailController loads, it immediately and one time only sets the $scope.selectedPerson to whatever is stored in ContactService.selectedPerson. It will never do this again unless the controller is recreated. So when PersonListController changes ContactService.selectedPerson, it actually changes the memory address ContactService.selectedPerson is pointing to. While PersonDetailController is still looking at the old memory address

Comment: This is a very common misconception about what is and what is not two-way data bound. Or at least how JavaScript variables are stored and referenced in memory

Comment: Ok i understand what you told. But then how does the dot Notation resolves the issue? Like lets say, if i store

$scope.contacts = ContractService.

Comment: It actually depends on your HTML. My solution assumes that somewhere in your HTML you are referencing `selectedPerson`. Using my solution, your HTML would be modified to `contacts.selectedPerson`. That dot there, means that when Angular runs its digest and checks each value again, it has to check contacts.selectedPerson. contacts doesn't change, its still your service, but it has to lookup selectedPerson again on contacts. It gets the current value everytime that way

Comment: So if you aren't referencing selectedPerson in your HTML, and you need to know when the value gets updated for controller behavior, then you are forced to use $watch

Comment: No actually i am referencing to selectedPerson in my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead of service (app.factory...)?

```
app.factory('ContactService', function() {
return{

    'selectedPerson': null ,
    'persons': [
        {
            "name": "Gregory Huffman",
            "email": "Praesent@pedenec.net",
            "birthdate": "2015-03-23T18:00:37-07:00",
            "phonenumber": "07624 073918",
            "address": "5880 Sed, Street",
            "city": "Denderbelle",
            "country": "Ethiopia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tad Vazquez",
            "email": "dapibus.gravida@necimperdietnec.co.uk",
            "birthdate": "2015-12-28T06:02:56-08:00",
            "phonenumber": "(016977) 1036",
            "address": "830-6354 Cubilia Rd.",
            "city": "Sulzbach",
            "country": "Liechtenstein"
        }]
};
});
```

Comment: @UditPanchal  let me know if two binding is not happening

Comment: Can you put a simple plunkr or jsfiddle. Will rectify the issue area.

Comment: Added the jsfiddle

Comment: The HTML is breaking somewhere. Can you check that? Change this implementation as well and checking into `ng-repeat="person in (persons | filter:sensitiveSearch | orderBy:order) track by $index"` Your controllers are fine. Some assignation issues but that should not impact persons object which should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the assignment to `$scope.selectedPerson` variable in `PersonDetailCtrl` is **call by value** which is leading to the reason your changes to the `ContactService` variable executed in `PersonListCtrl` are not visible in `PersonDetailCtrl`.

Once you make use of methods or assign `$scope.selectedPerson` variable in `PersonDetailCtrl` using **call by reference**, your issue will get resolved.

I have created one plnkr in which I made use of call by reference by using the reference of the `ContactService` in `PersonDetailCtrl`.

Refer the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rQUfLBhdSsv5mf46pX1e?p=preview

//HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example12-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
  <div ng-controller="PersonDetailController">
  PersonDetailController: {{contactSvc.selectedPerson.name || 'n/a'}}
</div>
<br/>

  <div ng-controller="PersonListController">

  PersonListController: {{selectedPerson.name || 'n/a'}} 
    <br/>
    <select ng-options="p.name for p in persons" ng-change="selectPerson()" ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

//JS

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])

.controller('PersonDetailController', function ($scope, ContactService, $rootScope){
  $scope.contactSvc = ContactService;

})

.controller('PersonListController', function ($scope, ContactService, $rootScope) {

  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.order = "email";
  $scope.persons = ContactService.persons;
  $scope.selectedPerson = ContactService.selectedPerson;
  $scope.selectPerson = function (person, index) {
      ContactService.selectedPerson = $scope.selectedPerson;
  };

  $scope.sensitiveSearch = function(person) {
      if ($scope.search) {
          return person.name.indexOf($scope.search) == 0 ||
                   person.email.indexOf($scope.search) == 0;
      }
      return true;
  };
})


.service('ContactService', function() {
return{

    'selectedPerson': null ,
    'persons': [
        {
            "name": "Gregory Huffman",
            "email": "Praesent@pedenec.net",
            "birthdate": "2015-03-23T18:00:37-07:00",
            "phonenumber": "07624 073918",
            "address": "5880 Sed, Street",
            "city": "Denderbelle",
            "country": "Ethiopia"
        },
        {
            "name": "Tad Vazquez",
            "email": "dapibus.gravida@necimperdietnec.co.uk",
            "birthdate": "2015-12-28T06:02:56-08:00",
            "phonenumber": "(016977) 1036",
            "address": "830-6354 Cubilia Rd.",
            "city": "Sulzbach",
            "country": "Liechtenstein"
        }]
};
})


})(window.angular);
```

I hope this answers your query!!